# На iphone не работает hover в меню

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, iphone, css

На iphone не работает это меню http://designmodo.com/demo/css3megamenu/. При нажатии не открываются подменю.

В интернете есть такое решение:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {
        $('.nav li a').click(function () {});
    }
</script>
```

Пробовал прописать перед html меню этот код, не помогло. Может что-то не так делаю?

Comment: Нужен код скрипта, который происходит при нажатии на менюшку. 
Без виденья кода, сложно сказать что не так

Answer (score 1):

Все дело в том, что iphone, iPod, iPad не поддерживает свойство :hover котрым сделано это меню. Для того что бы оно заработало, Вам предлагают подгрузить и модернизировать javascript под себя, котрый будет работать только в связке с jQuery.

Скрипт перехватывает действие "Клик", а далее Вы должны сами уже прописать что оно должно делать.

Например так:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {
    $('.nav li a').click(function () {
      $(this).children('div').slideDown();
    });
  }
</script>
```